# Can anyone help me understand this code ? Tensorflow Lite

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

In thensorflow-Lite Android App , We have to convert Bitmap to byte buffer and the code used for this is :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
    final int val = intValues[pixel++];
    imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what is Image Mean and STD , Also what is happening in these lines of code ?

Comment: `IMAGE_MEAN` and `IMAGE_STD` seem to be variables, initialized somewhere in either the method or as class variables.
Given they are all CAPS, they are likely to be class variables, likely final and possibly static.

A comment next to their initialization might give your more insight about their nature.
_(this is a good example showing why your should always comment your code for whoever might work on it later)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the code provided :

```
for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) { 
for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
```

Here, we create loops which would iterate over columns ( x axis ) and then over each pixel in the column ( y axis ).

- Here, `IMAGE_MEAN` is the mean of all pixel values of all images ranging from 0 to 255. It may be 127.5 ( mean of 0 and 255 )
- STD will be the standard deviation. It is the square root of the variance. Refer [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-probability-statistics-f830f8c09326).

These values are used for standardization. Standardization means tramsforming the data in such a way that the mean of the data is zero and standard deviation is 1. See [here](https://medium.com/predict/standardization-on-crazy-data-python-cd5b1282a97f). Here, the formula is,

> x_new = ( x - mean ) / std

The `putFloat` method is called 3 times on the `imgData` object since it appends the RGB standardized values to the list. Every pixel has these 3 values which are 3 scalars ranging between 0 and 255 which are standardized and appended.

- The >> operators get these 3 values from a single pixel integer value using bit operations. You can get info regarding them on the internet.

This path is followed :

- Reading the image pixel by pixel.
- Getting RGB values from the pixel.
- Standardizing the 3 values and storing them in a list.